# UITextField textInputView: message sent to deallocated instance（iOS 8 ）

Tags: memory-leaks, ios8

I have an issue where on the second time of displaying this interface tapping on the textField will cause the app to crash. How should I proceed in when debugging this crash, is there anything in the log to help me pin point the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to provide a clearer picture of what your asking help with. Remember the more information you can provide the greater chance you have of receiving help. For instance you may want to include the console output for the crash.

Comment: are you add any observer on the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I removed dealloc method crashes disappeared. Therefore I decided to find new way to implement autosuggestion feature.

The interesting thing is that I didn't import header file in code anywhere, but crashes occurred.

Comment: Is your UITextField at this class built themselves, look at the parent class